# Aggregate - count records with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I would like to count matching records with pymongo.
I have looked up the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-month-day-and-year

I understand that I should do something like:

```
db.foo_baz.aggregate([{'$group': {'_id': '$baz_id', 'count': {'$sum': 1}}}])
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongomock/collection.py", line 1531, in aggregate
    from_field = key.replace('$', '')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Add Comment

I would think that pymongo would evaluate it to this mongodb statement:

```
 db.foo_baz.aggregate({{$group: {_id: '$baz_id', count: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

Which gives me the expected result when ran from mongodb console, which is: `{"_id" : NumberInt("1234"), "count" : 1}` in my case.

What am I doning wrong? I am using pymongo 3.4 and python 3.6 and mongomock 3.7.

I have also tried replacing `1` with `"1"` which does not crash, but gives an incorrect result: (`{"_id" : NumberInt("1234"), "count" : NumberInt("0")}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently it's a bug in mongomock and after upgrade to 3.8 I get the expected behavior.